# Automapper how to map Custom interface between 2 generic types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have an interface:

```
public interface IQueryResult<T> where T : IBaseEntity
{
    PageInfo PageInfo { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Payload { get; }     
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class QueryResult<T> : IQueryResult<T> where T : IBaseEntity
{
    public QueryResult()
    {

    }
    public QueryResult(IEnumerable<T> payload, PageInfo pageInfo)
    {
        Payload = payload;
        PageInfo = pageInfo;
    }
    public QueryResult(IEnumerable<T> payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Payload { get; private set; }
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; private set; }
}
```

Mapper configuration:

```
    CreateMap<EntityA, DtoA>();
    CreateMap<DtoA, EntityA>();

    CreateMap<EntityB, DtoB>();
    CreateMap<DtoB, EntityB>();

    CreateMap(typeof(IQueryResult<>), typeof(IQueryResult<>));
```

Then I would like to do this in the controller:

```
IQueryResult<EntityA> entities = service.GetAll();
IQueryResult<DtoA> result = _mapper.Map<IQueryResult<DtoA>>(entities);
```

Currently, It does not break, but the problem is that since the properties have private setters the properties of the destination are null

I need somehow a way to tell it how to map the properties or use the constructor I guess

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it working if someone else comes along this problem I will leave this here:

After studying the Automapper documentation I came across this solution:

You can define an `ITypeConverter`

```
public class QueryResultConverter<TSource, TDest>
: ITypeConverter<IQueryResult<TSource>, IQueryResult<TDest>> where TSource: IBaseEntity where TDest : IBaseEntity
{
    public IQueryResult<TDest> Convert(IQueryResult<TSource> source, IQueryResult<TDest> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List <TDest> payload = context.Mapper.Map<List<TDest>>(source.Payload);
        destination = new QueryResult<TDest>(payload, source.PageInfo);

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Then you can configure the mapping to use the converter:

```
CreateMap(typeof(IQueryResult<>), typeof(IQueryResult<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(QueryResultConverter<,>));
```